# How do i pause an partal upgrade

Tags: update-manager, partial-upgrade

I have limited time and I would like to pause it so i can resume at home. 
so How do I pause it wile its installing packages? and how do I resume it? 
Also the WIFI is broken at home so it would be great if it will not delete what I have downloaded.

Comment: This question will probably be closed as a duplicate soon. If those answers don't fully address your question please edit it to include why and [flag this for re-opening](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/6073/44179). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

generally updates are `resumable` (not all but most of)

the partial downloads will not be deleted until

1).if the update (partially download) becomes absolute.

2).or you run any of these from terminal can cause to lose of partial downloaded update.

`sudo aptitude clean` - Will erase downloaded packages from cache

`sudo aptitude autoclean` - Will erase old downloaded packages from cache

`sudo apt-get clean` - Will erase downloaded packages from cache

`sudo apt-get autoclean` - Will erase old downloaded packages from cache

3). or you shut down your computer meanwhile your computer is `applying changes` can some time cause redownload of some of the packages (but not all)